# Making a more efficient function - Word counter

Tags: c

I'm going through some C programming questions and I want to make sure I got the fundamentals down. Currently I'm on a word counter question:

Q: Write a function which will determine how many words are in a given string. You can assume that one or more
consecutive white spaces is a delimiter between words, and that the string you pass to your function is null terminated.

I got the thing working, but efficiency is important. I'm wondering how it can be improved. Have to use pointers and no other library besides #include(stdio.h) Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int word_counter(char string[])
{
  //We start with first word unless we have a empty string then we have no words
  int count;
  if(*string!='\0'){
    count=1;
}
  else{
    count=0;
    return 0;
  }
  //while we dont reach the end of the string
  while(*string!='\0'){
    //if we detect a whitespace
    if(*string==' '){
      //get previous character
      string--;
      // If previous character is not a space we increase the count
      // Otherwise we dont since we already counted a word
      if(*string!=' '){
        count++;
      }
      //return pointer to current character
      string++;
    }
    // set pointer to next character
    string++;
  }
  return count;
}

//just to test if it works
int main(void) 
{
    char str[] = "Hello World!";
    printf("How many words? = %i\n", word_counter(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the string consists of whitespaces only? Your function'll return at least 1, which is wrong.

Comment: Since you state the code works, and you what you seem to want is a review of the code, I suggest posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a code review site.

Comment: [Has been done before plenty of times, don't re-invent the wheel](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=word+counter+%5Bc%5D).

Comment: Ok I'll check it out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I see there's a special case for the initial condition of an empty string. Sometimes getting the initial condition out of the way early simplifies the rest of the algorithm, sometimes you can eliminate it by changing how you look at the problem. This time it's the second one.

If you think about this as counting the boundaries between words, the algorithm becomes simpler. There's two ways to define a word boundary, from the front, and from the back.

```
"  Prestidigitation  \n"
   ^               ^
   front           back
```

Are we looking for a non-whitespace character after a whitespace character? Or are we looking for a whitespace character after a non-whitespace character?

You also have code that looks backwards in the string (`string--`), that's often not safe because what if the string starts with whitespace? Then you've walked backwards off the string, so moving backwards should be avoided.

Finally, there's the problem of whether or not there's any whitespace at the end of the string. We'd have to special case the end of the string.

So looking at the first word boundary is the way to go: a non-whitespace character after a whitespace character. Instead of looking backwards, we'll track the state of the previous character (`last_was_space` below).

That's a non-whitespace character after a whitespace character. What if the string doesn't start with whitespace?

```
"Basset hounds got long ears."
 ^
 What about this?
```

Since we have `last_was_space`, we can initialize it to true and pretend the start of the string starts with whitespace. This also handles leading whitespace like `"   this is four words"`.

Finally, there's more types of space than just space like tab and newline and other exotic stuff. Instead of writing `if( *space == ' ' || *space == '\n' == ... )` we can use `switch` to make things tidy and efficient. This is one of those rare cases where you want to take advantage of its "fall through" mechanic to do the same thing for multiple cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Note that it's `const` since we don't touch the string memory.
int word_counter(const char string[]) {
    // Start with no words.
    int count = 0;

    // Pretend every word starts with space.
    short last_was_space = 1;

    // Using a for loop to make the movement of the pointer more apparent
    for( ; *string!='\0'; string++ ) {
        // A switch can be faster than an if/else if.
        switch( *string ) {
            // There's more than one type of whitespace.
            // These are from isspace().
            // It takes advantage of switch's fall through.
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '\n':
            case '\r':
            case '\v':
            case '\f':
                // Remember we saw a space.
                last_was_space = 1;
                break;
            default:
                if( last_was_space ) {
                    // Non-whitespace after space, count it
                    count++;

                    // Remember we didn't see a space.
                    last_was_space = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Normally I'd use `bool` from [stdbool.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h) and `isspace` from [ctype.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification#Overview_of_functions), but your exercise can only use `stdio.h`.